# How to get a namespaced element in protractor using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

Protractor has [getAttribute](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute), so I can use the following using Chrome Driver and it will return the attribute content, but it will return null using Selenium Webdriver on Chrome (at least, the version 2.44.0 and 2.44.2).

```
element(by.Id('icon')).getAttribute('xlink:href').then(function(a){
  console.log('getAttribute:'+a);
});
```

Do you know how we can do the equivalent to that?

In raw DOM we can use the following and they will work:

```
document.getElementById('icon').getAttribute('xlink:href');
document.getElementById('icon').getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've solved it, using a workaround:

```
return element(by.Id('icon')).getOuterHtml().then(function(imageTag){
  var hrefImageRegex = imageTag.match(/xlink:href="(.*?)"/);
  return hrefImageRegex[1];
});
```